# Disable Multiline Textbox Resize Grip on Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, resize, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically creating controls, one of which is a multiline textbox.  I have seen links about how to do it when it is hard coded into my aspx page, however I can't do that since the control is dynamically generated.  I would like to avoid having to modify my .css files if possible. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, any advice would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general "resize:none" (there are funs of "overflow:auto") is the solution, therefore the typical option is to include it in your .css textarea definition and use the relative class name (if needed) in your aspx code. If needed means that by adding "textarea { resize: none; ... }" to your .css files there is no need to use CssClass in your asp:TextBox.

If you insist to not change your .css files, then you have to add a new css rule by JavaScript code somewhere (i.e. header control) on the server or add a new global .css file and serve it within your html header from aspx (this is better because you avoid checking existing css rules).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided that if a user chooses to mess up the formatting on the page by resizing the textbox, he/she knows it is going to happen. Marked as correct for a good answer, and clarity. (: